# Recording wav file in compressed format in iOS

Tags: ios

Right now i am using AQRecorder for recording audio as .wav. My audio file description is as below;

```
 mRecordFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
     mRecordFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
     mRecordFormat.mSampleRate = 8000.0;
     mRecordFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
     mRecordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
     mRecordFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
     mRecordFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
     mRecordFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2;
```

I want to know that can i record data to .wav in compressed format if yes please let me know how can i do this.(I dont want to record file in .caf format)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560011/compressed-and-uncompressed-wav-files gives some insights. Mind usually wave is uncompressed.